# Reactnative FlatList memory or is very Slow

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a big Flat List (around 2000 elements) ont the item i have
shouldComponentUpdate false so the item doesn't load several times

My FlatList is declared like this
<FlatList
showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
inverted
data={this.props.dataSourcePr}
ref={ref => {
this.state.flatListTimeLine = ref;
}}
renderItem={this.renderItem}
onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
viewabilityConfig={{
itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 30,
}}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
initialScrollIndex={this.state.lastIndex}
onScrollToIndexFailed={info => {}}

```
        initialNumToRender={70}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={50}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        windowSize={70}
        onScroll={this._onScroll}
        removeClippedSubviews = {true}
      />
```

How can i avoid crashes problem, and how can i make this FlatList less slow ? how can i tell FlatList to load only shown element on screen ?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to add keyExtractor and checkout this [article](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration) by react-native

Comment: Can you split that array is small chunks like 20 items, if that's not the case, Use component optimized for a huge large list? - https://github.com/bolan9999/react-native-largelist